# how to pass the form data and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am creating a website that has a form of following details:

1. Country code
2. mobile number
3. message
4. submit button

If any users fill the form and submit, I would like to pass that data to `www.example.com/subfolder/example.php` but after submission of data `example.php` redirects me in `www.example.com/index.html`.

So my question is: can I make a form so that the user could be redirected to the specific location that I want instead of to the current redirect to `www.example.com/index.html`

This is my form code, it is located at http://www.datafilehost.com/d/b68c527d

```
<form name="forma" method="post" id="myForm" action="www.example.com/subfolder/example.php">
  <input type="text" value="+977" id="Countrycodepre" name="Countrycodepre" readonly="readonly">
  <textarea wrap="off" autocomplete="off" cols="10" rows="1" type="text" name="country_mobile_number">
  <button name="submit" class="button100" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No one can help until you post some of your code. Can we see the form?

Comment: Just submit to `example.php`, and at the end of that file after the form has been parsed and you've done whatever it is you do, just redirect with a `header(`) call in PHP to `index.html`

Comment: Do you control the pages that you are posting to?

Comment: here is my form: @kdeisz

    <form name="forma"  method="post" id="myForm" action="www.example.com/subfolder/example.php">
    <input type="text" value="+977" id="Countrycodepre" name="Countrycodepre" readonly="readonly">
    <textarea wrap="off" autocomplete="off" cols="10" rows="1" type="text" name="country_mobile_number">
    <button name="submit"  class="button100" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: @Jeff I dont control but my friend controls it. He is refusing to give me source of the "example.php" file and challanged me to do this thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do this using a standard HTML form. The PHP page will redirect the browser to the new page and if you cant change the PHP, you cant affect the redirect.

Instead, you can post your form via AJAX. If you do this, your browser will not automatically follow the redirect. Then you can use JavaScript to redirect the page anywhere you want. If you go this way, you may be interested in using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Comment: i've not used AJAX yet. i'm a beginner and i'm learning php basics. i would be glad if you can help!

Comment: There's lots of people here at SO that are willing to help you out with any problems. JavaScript and jQuery have become a very big part of web development. You certainly would not be wasting your time if you tried to learn them. Give it a shot and if you have any questions, come back to SO and ask another question.

Comment: ok can you only give me idea how to post my form via AJAX

Comment: I did :) Use jQuery and the jQuery Form Plugin!

Comment: ok i will google it...if i didnt get any idea i will contact you..anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: can i use:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajax-remove-completion-date').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'www.example.com/subfolder/example.php',
            data: {
                submitted: 'www.pagetoredirect.com'
            },

        });
    });
});
@Jeff

Comment: Yes, that will submit the data to `example.php`. It will not do the redirect though. In the `complete` event in the `$.ajax`, you will need to make the redirect... `window.location.href = 'some_other_page.html'`

Comment: can you please reply me the full code? i am confused.

Answer (score 2):

take a div with style: display:none;

```
<iframe name="targetme" id="targetme" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Than give target of the for to "targetme" as :

```
<form target="targetme" method="post" action="www.example.com/subfolder/example.php">` <input type="text" value="+977" id="Countrycodepre" name="Countrycodepre" readonly="readonly"> 
<textarea wrap="off" autocomplete="off" cols="10" rows="1" type="text" name="country_mobile_number"> 
<button name="submit" class="button100" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button> `</form>
```

Comment: i should include '<form>' tag inside '<div>' or opposite?

Comment: No put them separate. you can add div either above form tag or below.

Comment: Please try frame tag instead of div but with same attributes
<frame name="targetme" id="targetme" style="display:none"></frame>

Comment: i tried your method and when i submit, i get a blank page but i get redirected to www.example.com/index.html in a new tab @NareshWalia

Comment: Use iframe instead of ferame. I just tested it

Comment: well thanks..that worked for me too...my original form page is not changed when i submit but the page 'www.example.com/index.html' is opened in another tab, could i prevent that?

Comment: could you please post the code again.

Comment: use this one (copy paste below code):
<form target="targetme" method="post" action="www.example.com/subfolder/example.php">
<input type="text" value="+977" id="Countrycodepre" name="Countrycodepre" readonly="readonly"> 
<textarea wrap="off" autocomplete="off" cols="10" rows="1" type="text" name="country_mobile_number"> </textarea>
<button name="submit" class="button100" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
<iframe name="targetme" id="targetme" style="display:none"></iframe>

Comment: the code is same as my question, i've added 'iframe' before the 'form' tag...now the only problem is to prevent the redirected page from opening in new tab..page redirection is done by 'example.php' on the server

Comment: do you have added target attribute in form tag?

Comment: yes i have added!! <form target="targetme" ....>

Comment: what is the name and id of iframe? also check the spelling of iframe

Comment: name of iframe is "myForm" id is also same and form tag also has attribute of target="myForm"

Comment: please post your updated code again so that i can review

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
header("Location: yourLocation.php");
```

to example.php.

Comment: the problem is 'i cant edit example.php' my friend gave me challange only he can control the php section

Comment: If he adds this, then your problem is solved.

Comment: according to my analysis his header has a location of www.example.com/index.html but i dont want to be redirected to that page.. i want to redirect to www.example.com/index2.html